# Inferred type parameter in generic typescript function is too wide

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to construct a function that **accepts a function** (react component) as an argument and subsequently **returns another (related) function**.

I'd like to constrain the incoming function to take arguments of a particular shape (specifically, assert that certain props are present).

I'd like to constrain the outgoing function such that the arguments and return type are related/inferred from the incoming function's "arguments of a particular shape".

**That's what I'm trying to do in words. In code, what I've come up with is:**

---

```js
function create<Props, A>(
    Component: (props: Props & { callback: (a: A) => void }) => any
): (props: Props) => Promise<A> {
    return null as any;
}

function MyComponent(
    props: {
        id: number,   // 'id' and 'name' should be inferred as 'Props'
        name: string,
        callback: (a: { id: number, status: string }) => void
                   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                   //   should be inferred as 'A'
    }
): void { }

const myComponent = create(MyComponent)

// error on the next line: expected 'callback' to be provided
myComponent({ id: 1, name: 'abc' }).then(res => {
    res.id;
    //  ^? (property) id: number
    res.status;
    //  ^? (property) name: string
})
```

[Here is TS playground link demonstrating the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQHgAopwAOAzgDSICCAfABQBQiTiAwnALZEJphQBciWkUKkBBYiUQAyRAG9kGADaKARhggBrAbQwDKASkQBeaogBucGABNEAX0MnEGMAE96+7cIliRJB6fF2GBJcGjlGZnQoEBQkIV9-RDA0AHdEQOC0BmYcwXQSOEUzNES2Tm5eWlkI3NyAOgavUjIa2uYIJVV1LUFdKkT5fMLinUNbVpz7Vv0Abnpx+lBIWAREAFkXMq5kytamkgFqtsRrATAQdhU0FBbjsAx2NAESKBQYMABzW7aO5TVNbR9eSnJIXK43RAvLAgA6Q17vD52RIWaytcYecyWGzyBYQBAvRDsTYcbY8KDGZDoLBZDZbCpQfT0ehEuk7KBVE5WAQARgo90eAgA5BgVBBBUi6lAABY8Wj5YymI6RNAkOrWOY5AD0mqYAD0APytfJ1KHREga5javWG+xAA)

Essentially, I'd like to ensure that `Component` has a `callback` prop, and I'd like for the outgoing (returned) function to take all the same props as `Component`, but without callback.

I'm also trying to infer the argument type for `callback` (so that it can be used in the returned function's return type `Promise<A>`).

---

From what I can tell `Props` is basically inferred to "include" `callback` as one of the properties.

If I try to explicitly `Omit<Props, 'callback'>` in the returned function I instead get the error:

```
'Props' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Omit<Props, "callback"> & { callback: (a: A) => void; }'
```

[Here is a TS playground link demonstrating this other error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQHgAopwAOAzgDSICCAfABQBQiTiAwnALZEJphQBciWkUKkBBYiUQAyRAG9kGADaKARhggBrAbQwDKASkQBeaogBucGABNEAX0MnEGMAE96+7cIkCA8uxhQ+CLkiADkEEqq6hqh1A6m4v4kuDRyjMzoUCAoSELB8YhgaADuiIkwyQzM1YLoJHCKZmgFbJzcvLSy6TU1AHT9XqRk3T3MEcpqmtq6VAXydQ1NOoa2I9X2I-oA3PSr9KCQsAiIALIurVxFHSODJAJdo4jWAmAg7CpoKMOPYBjsaAISFAUDAwABzb6jcZRKaCGbyZ6FN4fL6IIFYEB3NHA0FguwFCzWEarDzmSw2eR7CAIIGIdjnDiXHhQYzIdBYNC0M4XdpQfT0ej0nlXKCdJ5WAQARgov3+AlCGBUEFC+N6UAAFjxaHVjKYHhk0CRetYdtUAPRmpgAPQA-CM6r10VkSKbmBbrXb7EA)

I'm wondering if anyone can help me figure out if what I'm trying to do can be done and/or what I'm missing?

Comment: I would just cast (assert) and call it a day: https://tsplay.dev/wXqYON

Comment: Honestly, hadn't thought of that. Fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could just assert that what you're giving to `Component` is the correct type:

```
function create<Props, A>(
    Component: (props: Props & { callback: (a: A) => void }) => any
): (props: Omit<Props, "callback">) => Promise<A> {
    return (props) => new Promise(
        (resolve) => Component({
            ...props,
            callback: (a: A) => { resolve(a) }
        } as Props)
    );
}
```

But you'll notice that when we do so, we get an error:

> Argument of type 'Props' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Props & { callback: (a: A) => void; }'.
> Type 'Props' is not assignable to type '{ callback: (a: A) => void; }'.(2345)
> input.tsx(1, 17): This type parameter might need an `extends { callback: (a: A) => void; }` constraint.

So then that's why I've added the generic constraint to `Props`:

```
function create<Props extends { callback: (a: A) => void }, A>(
```

and now it works as expected.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=59&pln=1&pc=22#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQHgAopwAOAzomgB7ZgAmZA3shgDbMBGGEA1gFyIAUGPgEEAlIgC8APkQA3ODBqIAvgBpEwqfwBQiPYgDCcALZEEaMFD78ihUnwLEyAMkSMILdp14ChG8dJyCkrKATIYYACe2qLWtk58APLGMFD4diTqAEQerBzcWVJhiI4pJLiabrr66FAgKEg2GcVgaADuJYRlaDr6fQLoJHDMsmjFRqbmlvz01f39AHRL8aSqc-P6uV7c1n5ikjKMg8OjguLK633KiBhkjqSi66IA3NoX2qCQsAiIALKREzMrWm6xWJD4sw2iEUfDAIGMbDQKDWULAGGMaD4JCgKBgYAA5iiNlt8j5BBDoTRYfDEcjENisCBwfScXj8SpivJFOsLrEgoo3CptNoIAhsYhjACTECLFBJMh0Fgev9AVMoI9tJLVcCoDNKXwAIzqNEYvgAcgwbAgZo5CygAAsLPxBgcqn1BgtFK8+gB6H16AB6AH51h6GXUSN79H7AyHQkA)

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why we need both `Props extends { callback: (a: A) => void }` as a constraint _and_ `Component: (props: Props & { callback: (a: A) => void }) => any` in the function argument? Naively, I would think that just constraining `Props` with `extends` would be enough, and that one wouldn't need to seemingly "repeat" this constraint in the argument (i.e. with `Component: (props: Props & { callback: (a: A) => void }) => any`) and instead just have: `Component: (props: Props) => any`.

Comment: @AndrewRoss If you don't include `& { callback: ... }` then TypeScript has no "source" to infer `A` from, and so `A` defaults to `unknown`, making `create(MyComponent)` throw an error.

Comment: I see, I think I follow, essentially the constraint is saying "At a minimum `Props` looks like this", and the intersection in the argument is basically saying "infer A (and Props) from here". Could one replace Props extends { callback: (a: A) => void }` with `Props extends { callback: (a: any) => any }`?

Comment: Dumb question - just tried it. It works! Thanks again @caTS :)